# Yelp API authentication with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm attempting to issue a GET request to Yelp's API in order to perform a simple search using both Express and Nodejs, however I'm having trouble understanding how to set the request header with the provided API key. Using `request` I attempted to pass basic authentication following the documentation yet I'm receiving errors. Using `setHeader` I also received errors.

Using Postman I am able to enter the API keys and receive responses with no issue. I understand packages are out there for this but I think it might be good to learn without the use of additional dependencies if possible.

```
var express = require("express"); 
var app = express();
var request = require("request");

request.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search', function (error, 
response, body) {
'auth': {
  'bearer': 'api_key_here'
}
});

app.listen(3000)
```

Edit: I was able to fix the callback function(it was passing the header), and am now able to run, however I am now getting `{"error": {"code": "TOKEN_MISSING", "description": "An access token must be supplied
 in order to use this endpoint."}}` . Still confused what I'm doing wrong here as the API key is working properly in POSTMAN.

```
var express = require("express"); 
var app = express();
var request = require("request");

request.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search', {
'Authorization': {
Bearer: 'api key'
}}
function(error, response, body){
console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using express.js to implement Yelp API, but I found using [yelp-fushion](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/tree/master/fusion/node) much easier.

I implemented it like below:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const yelp = require('yelp-fusion');

const apiKey = process.env.YELP_API_KEY;

const searchRequest = {
  term: 'restaurants',
  location: 'Los Angeles',
};

const client = yelp.client(apiKey);

client.search(searchRequest)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.jsonBody);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

First line is to use .env file.
I saved my Yelp API key in .env file like this: `YELP_API_KEY=6fNc0sj5Oyt_jsU2gdeDrlo_1NLm5c-df3f`.
Then I assigned it to `const apiKey` and used it as an argument of `yelp.client()`

yelp-fushion's [docs](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_search) gives you more details on parameters for businesses search.

Lastly, `client.search()` method will return response.jsonBody containing all the data that you need.

Comment: Yep, this worked however I was trying to make calls without using any type of additional package if necessary. I initially thought this was as a simple as setting the header's authorization but apparently not.